# How to limit the number of entities returned from a fetch request in Swift UI?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I'm looking for a way to only get the first instance of my fetch request in Swift UI `@FetchRequest(entity: Solve.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Solve.date, ascending: false)]) var solves: FetchedResults<Solve>`
So then I could get the only a singular entity out. 
Thanks!